# Using "a" tag to run php code on same page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, hyperlink

I'm using an "a href" tag that links to same page. Using jQuery i've set it to `event.preventDefault` and so the page doesn't refresh. When i click on that link it runs the php code on the same page and updates the database as required , but i also want it to "echo" the returned result using mysql and that does not happen. Has anyone got a better idea?

I want the result to return without reload and i cant use ".load " or such jQuery functions as it affects my other part of the application.

EDIT
MY php code that runs but doesn't show the result

```
$queryCC="UPDATE test SET count='$Count' WHERE name='$xyz' ";
$resultCC=mysql_query($queryCC,$db) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$queryCT="SELECT count FROM test WHERE name='$getInc' ";
$resultCT=mysql_query($queryCT,$db) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$extractChSt=mysql_fetch_array($resultCT);
echo $getPRevCount=$extractChSt['count'];
```

The html link

```
<a href="index?param=xyz" class="ECvesnd">Click</a>
```

Jquery

```
$('.ECvesnd').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href
    });
});
```

Comment: Show your code please - because you can't run php code in a javascript function.

Comment: If you think AJAX "affects other parts of the application," chances are that you're doing it wrong or there's something seriously wrong with the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `success` callback to capture the returned (echo 'your result' on server side) data from the server and show it on the client side, for example :

```
$('.ECvesnd').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

[Look at jQuery documentation for more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".ECvesnd" ).click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:this.href ,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: i've tried this but i want that 'data' to be shown in a div , by using ${'#div').html(data) it display full page since i'm returning data from same page

Comment: Yes you can just change the alert box  in the above code to $("#div").html(data); I guess "div" is the id of your div tag.Then this wil work

Comment: Have you checked it ?